# How do I parse a string in bash into variables using a tab as the delimiter and preserve spaces?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

I am in the process of writing a bash script to display various statistics, some of which come from a MySQL database. The pertinant code I'm having difficulty with is:

```
read min max rows <<< $(mysql $dbDatabase -u $dbUser -p$dbPass -B -N -e \
    "SELECT MIN(\`DateTime\`), MAX(\`DateTime\`), COUNT(*) FROM $dbTable")
echo "Min Date:" $min
echo "Max Date:" $max
echo "Total Rows:" $rows
```

The result of its execution is:

```
Min Date: 2013-03-18
Max Date: 20:30:00
Total Rows: 2014-07-31 14:30:00 11225139
```

Which obviously is not what I intend (the DateTime value has been split)

According to Google, `$IFS` should be the answer to my problem. Unfortunately, I'm still unsuccessful in parsing the results correctly.

```
IFS=$'\t' read min max rows <<< ...
```

The result is:

```
Min Date: 2013-03-18 20:30:00 2014-07-31 14:30:00 11225139
Max Date:
Total Rows:
```

I find this odd since `msyql -B | tr $'\t' 'X'` proves visually that the fields are separated by tabs.

As a workaround, I can do something like the following to produce the desired output:

```
read min max rows <<< $(mysql $dbDatabase -u $dbUser -p$dbPass -B -N -e \
    "SELECT MIN(\`DateTime\`), MAX(\`DateTime\`), COUNT(*) FROM $dbTable" \
    | tr ' ' '.')
min=$(tr '.' ' ' <<< $min)
max=$(tr '.' ' ' <<< $max)

echo "Min Date:" $min
echo "Max Date:" $max
echo "Total Rows:" $rows
```

But that hardly seems elegant or the "unix way".

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and why `$IFS` isn't working for me, and what the correct usage is to have clean (non-hacky) and understandable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the result of the command substitution, i.e. `"$(command)"` I think e.g. (simulating your query with an `echo`):

```
$ IFS=$'\t' read min max rows <<< "$(echo -e "Wed Jul 30 15:40:38 EDT 2014\tThu Jul 31 15:40:38 EDT 2014\t27")"
$ echo "$min"; echo "$max"
Wed Jul 30 15:40:38 EDT 2014
Thu Jul 31 15:40:38 EDT 2014
```

or use a (more direct) *process substitution* instead

```
$ IFS=$'\t' read min max rows < <(echo -e "Wed Jul 30 15:40:38 EDT 2014\tThu Jul 31 15:40:38 EDT 2014\t27")
$ echo "$min"; echo "$max"
Wed Jul 30 15:40:38 EDT 2014
Thu Jul 31 15:40:38 EDT 2014
```